# Why does my useState value reset in onPress method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I'm using a useState called tripState in my react native component.

```js
const [tripState, setTripState] = useState<NewTripState>({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    thumbnail: "",
});
```

I change its value in text field using function:

```js
const onChange = (
    key: keyof NewTripState,
    value: string | null,
): void => {
    setTripState({
        ...tripState,
        [key]: value,
    });
};
```

Text input:

```js
<TextInput
    value={tripState.name}
    onChangeText={(value: string): void => {
        onChange("name", value);
    }}
    placeholder={"Enter trip name"}
/>
```

which is called on text inputs. If I console.log the value in:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tripState); // console.logs updated state
}, [tripState]);
```

it console logs correct (updated) value, but the moment i try to console log it in my `onSubmit` method which is called on `onPress` on `Pressable`, I get the initial value.

```js
<Pressable onPress={onSubmit}>
    <Text>Save</Text>
</Pressable>
```

```js
const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(tripState); // console.logs initial state
};
```

Can someone please help me? I don't know that to do anymore.

Edit 1:
Entire component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { getUserHoliday } from "../../api/firestore/trips";
import ProfilePicture from "../../components/ProfilePicture";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Pressable,
} from "../../components/Themed";
import { tintColorLight } from "../../constants/Colors";
import store from "../../redux/store";
import { getUserId } from "../../redux/stores/user";
import { Holiday } from "../../utils/types/holiday";
import { Trip } from "../../utils/types/trip";

type NewTripScreenProps = {
    navigation: any;
    route: any;
};

export type NewTripState = {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    thumbnail: string;
};

const NewTripScreen = (props: NewTripScreenProps) => {
    const { navigation } = props;

    const [tripState, setTripState] = useState<NewTripState>({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        thumbnail: "",
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(tripState);
    }, [tripState]);

    const onChange = (
        key: keyof NewTripState,
        value: string | null,
    ): void => {
        setTripState((currentValue) => ({
            ...currentValue,
            [key]: value,
        }));
    };

    const userId = getUserId(store.getState());

    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserHoliday(userId).then((holidays) => {
            setHolidays(holidays);
        });

        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: "New Trip",
            headerRight: () => (
                <Pressable onPress={onSubmit}>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            color: tintColorLight,
                            fontSize: 18,
                        }}
                    >
                        Save
                    </Text>
                </Pressable>
            ),
            headerTintColor: tintColorLight,
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: colorScheme === "dark" ? "#fff" : "#000",
            },
        });
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = () => {
        console.log(tripState.name);

        const trip: Trip & { holiday?: Holiday | null } = {
            userId: userId,
            ...tripState,
            status: "created",
        };
    };

    return (
            <View>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontSize: 32,
                        padding: 10,
                    }}
                >
                    New Trip
                </Text>
                <View style={{ alignItems: "center", marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={tripState.name}
                        onChangeText={(value: string): void => {
                            onChange("name", value);
                        }}
                        placeholder={"Enter trip name"}
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        value={tripState.description}
                        onChangeText={(value: string): void => {
                            onChange("description", value);
                        }}
                        placeholder={"Enter Description"}
                        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                    />
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            fontSize: 32,
                            padding: 10,
                        }}
                    >
                        Thumbnail
                    </Text>
                    <ProfilePicture
                        photoURL={tripState.thumbnail}
                        onPress={() => {}}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
    );
};

export default NewTripScreen;
```

Comment: Add all the code in question

Comment: there is no other code using the useState in any way so its not really necessary to add anything else.

Comment: @LukášPeťko: If you're able to replicate the problem in a relatively small component (which contains only the code shown above, but in a complete and runnable component) then posting that component in its entirety could indeed be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of useEffect with empty dependency array. When you add `onSubmit()` on Pressable's onPress listener, because of useEffect with empty dependency array the original value of tripState inside `onSubmit` is used.

Change the code like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getUserHoliday(userId).then((holidays) => {
            setHolidays(holidays);
        });

        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: "New Trip",
            headerTintColor: tintColorLight,
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: colorScheme === "dark" ? "#fff" : "#000",
            },
        });
    }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
       navigation.setOptions({
           headerRight: () => (
                <Pressable onPress={onSubmit}>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            color: tintColorLight,
                            fontSize: 18,
                        }}
                    >
                        Save
                    </Text>
                </Pressable>
            )
           });
    }, [tripState]);
```

Comment: You can take a look at these [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions)

Answer (score 0):

The topic you're looking for is called 'stale values'. It's what happens when values get locked in to your function, and don't refresh. React useState has a way of solving this, really simply:

Instead of:

```
setTripState({
  ...tripState,
  [key]: value,
});
```

Tell the setState that you want to use the most up-to-date value:

```
setTripState(currentValue => ({
  ...currentValue,
  [key]: value,
}));
```

Comment: But when the OP logs the value in useEffect, updated value is logged

Comment: sadly this didn't solve the issue